# Java LDAP get direct reports Multiple Levels in a single query

Tags: java, ldap

I need to write a Java application in which it queries LDAP and gets all the User hierarchy information by reading the "Direct Reports" attributes or any other way if possible. i.e.Multiple Levels of a user/Manager and their subordinates and their subordinates etc.
I can do this by querying individually for each users. 
There is a disadvantage in this case, it queries LDAP for each user and doing so will take a enormous time to get the result set.
I am looking for a single individual query/LDAP filter or a robust code that can fetch up to 3-4 levels of data, so that I can enumerate and use the data as required.

please help me if anyone has done this before or having fair idea/suggestions on this issue.

regards,
Srinath

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the exact requirements, the subtree specification and/or collective attributes might give some ideas. RFC 3672 and RFC 3671.